# CosmosDB throughput increases automatically causing subsequent executions of Terraform to fail

Tags: mongodb, azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb

I use the following Terraform configuration to generate an empty CosmosDB database with the throughput set to 400. After that, the Spring application connects to the database and creates five collections which increases the throughput to 500. When I execute the Terraform next time it recognizes the change of throughput and it wants to make an update: *~ throughput= 500 -> 400*, which causes an **Error waiting on ThroughputUpdate future for Cosmos Mongo Database** since this kind of update is not allowed. What could be the solution to deal with this problem since I don't want to use autoscaling?

```
// create a database inside specified Cosmos DB account
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database" "project_db" {
    name                = "__dbName__"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db_account.resource_group_name
    account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db_account.name
    // (optional) provision throughput which can be shared between collections
    throughhput          = 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use *ignore_changes* which ignores the changes of throughput:

```
// create a database inside specified Cosmos DB account
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database" "project_db" {
    name                = "__dbName__"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db_account.resource_group_name
    account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db_account.name
    // (optional) provision throughput which can be shared between collections
    throughput          = 400
    lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [throughput]
     }
}
```